# Forum lay out problem

Tags: nodes

I'm having some problems with my forum, I messed up my lay out and can't seem to get it back. Reinstalling the Advanced Forum module doesn't help.

[image: Problem]

Does anyone know how to get my text to the right, in other words next to the red line I drew? Also it doesn't register my 'enter' clicks, so a reply is just plain text without structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome right click on the text and choose 'inspect element'. Find the css selector for that element. Then go into the stylesheet for your theme, and add a rule there to add margin-left to the text.

It sounds like it might be a javascript problem if you can't click a certain link. Check javascript errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the new lines not working the most likely problem is that you are using a filtered html text mode and that `<p>` and/or `<br>` are not accepted tags. Set it to full HTML or a filtered text mode which accepts paragraph and break tags.